# Conky top bar that stretches across the whole screen

Tags: conky

How does a minimal conky config look like to draw a persistent top bar that stretches horizontally across the entire visible screen?

[image: Conky top bar (orange) stretching across the screen (green)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#if screen resolution = 1280x1024  
alignment bottom_left  
#bigger number = thinner bar  
gap_y 950  
minimum_size 1280
```

Comment: Welcomme to U&L, maybe you can provide some details about your resolution (meaning of parameter for instance) ?